# What is the correct way to retrieve timezone aware datetime objects from a cx_oracle cursor?

Tags: python, oracle, internationalization, cx-oracle

cx_oracle returns `datetime` instances for columns of the `TIMESTAMP` or `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` types, but these datetime instances are not timezone aware.

For example:

```
SELECT column_name, data_type FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE table_name = 'mytable';

column_name data_type
----------- ---------------------------
MYCOL       TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE
```

As you can see, MYCOL is a TIMESTAMP which is timezone aware. I would expect that the following would return a Python datetime object that contains tzinfo data. However:

```
>>> cxoracle_cursor.execute("select mycol from mytable")
>>> row = cx_oracle_cursor.fetchone()
>>> row['mycol']
datetime.datetime(2011, 6, 15, 8, 30)
```

That datetime object isn't timezone aware, so I can't reliable use this date in my application.

What is the best approach to retrieving this column as a datetime object that is timezone aware?

Answer (score 3):

[Here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch4datetime.htm) I see the following: *For TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE data, the datetime value is always in UTC, so no conversion is necessary.*

So if you get the `datetime` object timezone unaware, I understand it is in UTC. So you can do:

```
dt = pytz.utc.localize(row['mycol'])
```

Or try the function `SYS_EXTRACT_UTC` (*Extracts the UTC from a datetime with time zone offset*) and then with `pytz.utc.localize`.

Comment: Thanks for the information. SYS_EXTRACT_UTC works exactly as you mention and could lead to a solution, however it does not appear that cx_oracle is marshalling mycol either by converting to a UTC datetime, or adding some tzinfo to the datetime. It appears to be returning a naive datetime object local to whatever timezone it is stored as in Oracle (but without tzinfo data).

Comment: I'm getting the same result as @StephenEmslie: `cx_Oracle` is simply returning a `datetime` object which is the naïve timezone-unaware truncation of the `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`.

Comment: It's worth seeing the ongoing [issue discussion](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/issues/13) on the `cx_Oracle` project at Github. **tl;dr** There will likely be a way to transparently pass `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` objects in and out of `cx_Oracle` with Python 3.10. 